# How to set settings of plugin Redactor

Tags: craft3, redactor, editor

I install plugin "Redactor"(version. 3.0.3) (https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/v2/README.md). I use this type field for full text of article. I cant understand how to set the place for image. How to set directory? With default settings when i click on icon "image" opened modal window, but this window is empty. I think problem in settings of plugin. But where to set this settings, i can't understand. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I read aloud was a bit hard to follow, but I believe I understand what you are trying to convey. You will need to go to the Control Panel and navigate to Settings. Once there, click on the fields button/icon. You will need to create a new Field Type called Redactor. Once you are there, you should be able to configure the Redactor buttons by clicking on "Redactor Config."

When you use the Redactor image button, you can set the directory for your images by going to "Available Volumes."

[image]

Comment: Thank you, friend. My English is a little bad. I wrote as best I could. Your decision helped)